# SQLite3 iOS Segmentation Fault (Xamarin)

Tags: ios, xamarin, sqlite, xamarin.ios

I am having a difficult time diagnosing a segmentation fault thrown inside of sqlite3. I can narrow the entry point down to a single query on my code, after which the stack never returns to my code and blows up in sqlite3.

I understand this may not be an issue with sqlite3 but from the message and stack trace given, I don't know where to begin.

My code-

```
private Session GetCurrentSession()
{
    return Database.Query<Session>("select * from Session").FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Stack Trace starting at the last call from my code-

> Thread 0 name:  tid_a0b  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>   Thread 0 Crashed:
>
> 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x23d86c5c __pthread_kill + 8
>
> 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x23e30732 pthread_kill + 62
>
> 2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x23d1b0ac abort + 108
>
> **3   MyMobileAppiOS              0x0011e834 mono_handle_native_sigsegv (mini-exceptions.c:2420)**
>
> **4   MyMobileAppiOS              0x0012612c mono_sigsegv_signal_handler (mini-runtime.c:2875)**
>
> **5   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x23e2a076 _sigtramp + 42**
>
> 6   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x2453cc34 0x2451d000 + 130100
>
> 7   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x2453cc34 0x2451d000 + 130100
>
> 8   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x2453cb4a 0x2451d000 + 129866
>
> 9   libsqlite3.dylib                  0x2452809a 0x2451d000 + 45210
>
> 10  libsqlite3.dylib                  0x245269e2 0x2451d000 + 39394
>
> 11  libsqlite3.dylib                  0x24526128 0x2451d000 + 37160
>
> 12  libsqlite3.dylib                  0x24525aa4 0x2451d000 + 35492
>
> 13  libsqlite3.dylib                  0x2452583e 0x2451d000 + 34878
>
> 14  libsqlite3.dylib                  0x24567e50 sqlite3_prepare_v2 + 44
>
> **15  MyMobileAppiOS              0x00a2bba0 wrapper_managed_to_native_SQLitePCL_SQLite3Provider_default_NativeMethods_sqlite3_prepare_v2_intptr_byte___int_intptr__intptr_ (/:1)**
>
> 16  MyMobileAppiOS                0x00a1c754 SQLitePCL_SQLite3Provider_default_SQLitePCL_ISQLite3Provider_sqlite3_prepare_v2_intptr_string_intptr__string_ (/:1)
>
> 17  MyMobileAppiOS                0x00a18aa8 SQLitePCL_raw_sqlite3_prepare_v2_SQLitePCL_sqlite3_string_SQLitePCL_sqlite3_stmt__string_ (/:1)
>
> 18  MyMobileAppiOS                0x00a189f8 SQLitePCL_raw_sqlite3_prepare_v2_SQLitePCL_sqlite3_string_SQLitePCL_sqlite3_stmt_ (/:1)
>
> 19  MyMobileAppiOS                0x009ec278 SQLite_SQLite3_Prepare2_SQLitePCL_sqlite3_string (SQLite.cs:3322)
>
> 20  MyMobileAppiOS                0x009e5e00 SQLite_SQLiteCommand_Prepare (SQLite.cs:2289)
>
> 21  MyMobileAppiOS                0x009e750c SQLite_SQLiteCommand__ExecuteDeferredQueryc__Iterator0_1_T_REF_MoveNext (SQLite.cs:2201)
>
> 22  MyMobileAppiOS                0x002a0db8 System_Collections_Generic_List_1_T_REF__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_1_T_REF + 596
>
> 23  MyMobileAppiOS                0x005b0ae4 System_Linq_Enumerable_ToList_TSource_REF_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_1_TSource_REF (Enumerable.cs:861)
>
> 24  MyMobileAppiOS                0x009e58c8 SQLite_SQLiteCommand_ExecuteQuery_T_REF (SQLite.cs:2170)
>
> 25  MyMobileAppiOS                0x009debb0 > SQLite_SQLiteConnection_Query_T_REF_string_object__ (SQLite.cs:711)
>
> **26  MyMobileAppiOS              0x009c4344 MyMobileAppiOS_SQLiteAccess_Repository_SqlSessionRepository_GetCurrentSession (SqlSessionRepository.cs:35)**

This line gets called when the app launches. The app crashes 50% of the time. I understand whats given may not be enough to solve the problem, but I was hoping from the stack trace and call someone could give me direction on what might cause this problem.

**EDIT-**

Looks like this is not limited to this query and can happen anytime `Database.Query` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was difficult to find. But maybe this will help someone else who stumbles on this same error.

In one of the queries a column names was incorrect. Instead of getting an error related to an incorrect column name, the error was a seg fault.

To track down this issue, we have to make most of our asynchronous tasks run synchronously before the debugger caught the error. Apparently in iOS, if a thread fails, the entire application fails. In android, it just ignores it and moves on.

Check your queries and make sure you're not referencing columns that don't exist.